# LINQ JOIN in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have created a `join` with LINQ, and I'm wondering if there's a better way to accomplish it.

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Prices>> GetTicketsPrices(db501Context _context,string Provider)
{
    int ProviderKey = 0;
    switch (Provider)
    {
        case "A":
           ProviderKey = 1;
            break;

        case "B":
            ProviderKey = 2;
            break;

        default:
            ProviderKey = 0;
            break;
    }


    var voucherPrices = await _context.VoucherPrices.Select(r => r).ToListAsync();
    var Providers = await _context.VoucherProviders.Select(p => p).ToListAsync();
    var voucherTypes = await _context.VoucherTypes.Select(t => t).ToListAsync();
    var passengerType = await _context.VouchersPassengerTypes.Select(pt => pt).ToListAsync();

    var newQueryObjectResult = from price in voucherPrices
                               join provider in Providers on price.Provider equals provider.Id
                               join type in voucherTypes on price.Type equals type.Id
                               join passenger in passengerType on price.PassengerType equals passenger.Id
                               where provider.Id == ProviderKey
                               select new Prices { Provider = provider.Name, PassengerType = passenger.Description,Type = type.Description,Price = price.Price};

    return newQueryObjectResult;
}
```

Currently, I'm getting data from the `context` four times. Each model's list result is assigned to a different variable.

Is this the best way of doing that? Can I use the context only one time in order to retrieve all the data besides using a stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this instead:

```cs
var prices = await (
    from price in _context.VoucherPrices
    where provider.Id == ProviderKey
    select new Prices
    {
        Provider = price.Provider.Name,
        PassengerType = price.PassengerType.Description,
        Type = price.Type.Description,
        Price = price.Price
    }
).ToListAsync();
```

This is just using the navigation properties instead of manual joins. You would just need to be careful that there were records tied to the foreign keys (or do `null` checks instead), like:

```cs
Provider = price.Provider != default ? price.Provider.Name : default,
PassengerType = price.PassengerType != default ? price.PassengerType.Description : default,
Type = price.Type != default ? price.Type.Description : default
```

Comment: just perfect! works like a charm with the navigation.